# Android autocomplete dropdownlist

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have implemented the autocomplete textview in my android app this way:

```
String countries[] = { "Roma", "Arcinazzo Romano", "Bagnara di Romagna", "Bagno di Romagna", "Barbarno Romano",
        "INDONESIA", "UK", "Campagnano di Roma", "Bassano Romano" };

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
 edittext_city = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext_city);
 adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
 adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

edittext_city.setThreshold(3);
                edittext_city.setMaxLines(1);
                edittext_city.setAdapter(adapter1);
                edittext_city.getCompletionHint();
```

the autocomplete works fine but when i  am writing "Roma" in the result list show "Roma" value and the other element of array that have the letter 'roma' in the string.
Why? If i write the specific string that is into array the result must be the only one string.
How i can resolve this?

Thanks

Thanks for your replay i have changed my code to read the value by db and i have try to implement your idea but with out result. This is the new code:

```
 edittext_city = (AutoCompleteTextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext_city);
                    if(FirstProjectApplication.allComunesName.size() == 0)
                    {
                        DBProvider provider = new DBProvider(getActivity());
                        database_comune_dao comune_dao = new database_comune_dao(provider.getDb());
                        FirstProjectApplication.allComunesName = comune_dao.getAllComuneName();
                        provider.close();
                    }

                    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FirstProjectApplication.allComunesName);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    edittext_city.setAdapter(adapter);
                    edittext_city.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                        }

                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charsequence, int j, int k, int l)


                        {
                        }

                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charsequence, int j, int k, int l) {
                        }

                    });
```

Any example to see???
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter view with filterable.
Please refer following link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html